# Empty Space in Safari on right side

Tags: html, css, safari, bootstrap-4, mobile-safari

I am at a loss and hoping you guys can help. I built my site using bootstrap 4.1, my website is http://www.visionary-creatives.com/ It seems to function as expected in chrome, firefox, and opera and IE. When I run it on Safari there is a white space on the right side, giving it a side scrolling function which is not intended.

I've gone through it line by line and checked width, and there doesn't appear to be overflowing which is causing it. I've also tried adding

```
 html, body {
   width:100%;
   overflow-x:hidden;
 }
```

This worked to fix the white space that's rendering. Unfortunately it also disabled my navbar from scrolling on those websites as well, and completely disabled mobile navigation. Sorry I don't have the entire code posted here, it's obviously long. If this question has been answered I'm sorry, I checked and couldn't find an answer regarding this.

Comment: There is no side scrolling for me in IE.

Comment: I just realized, I checked it in safari with developer tools simulating IE. So I suspect that it was not using their functions. I'll update the question. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your bootstrap.css, find line #571:

```
#devDiv1, #devDiv2, #devDiv3 {
    margin-top: 85px;
    margin-bottom: -24px;
    position: relative;
    height: inherit;
    perspective: 150px;
    perspective-origin: 0 50%;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

Add `overflow: hidden;` there.

Comment: Thank you so much! I knew it was something simple I had missed. Worked perfectly

Comment: @ChrisHitchcock, happy to help!